# How to print employeenames in a company in java

Tags: java

```
//company array
public Company[] save() {
    Company []com=new Company[5];
    com[0]=new Company("abc",123,"abc@gmail.com",57839174,"abc.com",City.THRISSUR);
    com[1]=new Company("cde",456,"cde@gmail.com",47578317,"cde.com",City.TRIVANDRUM);
    com[2]=new Company("fgh",789,"fgh@gmail.com",82239129,"fgh.com",City.KOCHI);
    com[3]=new Company("ijk",127,"ijk@gmail.com",45758379,"ijk.com",City.KOZHIKODE);
    com[4]=new Company("lmn",845,"lmn@gmail.com",65893948,"lmn.com",City.KODUNGALLUR);
    
    
    return com;
    
}
//prints all companies
public void showData(){
    save();
    Company[] com=save();

    for(int i=0;i<com.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(com[i].toString());
    }
     }
//prints if company name exists
public void comparecompany() {
    save();
    Company[] com = save();

    String a="lmn";
    boolean found=false;
    for(int i =0;i<com.length;i++) {
        String b=a.toLowerCase();
        
        
        if(com[i].getcompanyname().equals(b)) {
            System.out.println("company exist");
            found=true;
            break;
        }}
    if(found==false)
          System.out.println("company doesnt exist");
        
    }
//prints all companyname starting with "a"
public void starta() {
    save();
    Company[] com = save();
    //show names containing the letter starting as the first letter
    
    for(int i=0;i<com.length;i++) {
        String comp=(String)com[i].getcompanyname();
    if(comp.startsWith("a")) {
         System.out.println(comp);
    }}
    
    
        
    
} 
// to print employees in a company
public void empcompany() {
    save();
    Company[] com = save();
    saves();
    Employee[]emp=saves();
    String comp="abc";
    boolean found=false;
    for(int i=0;i<com.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<emp.length;j++) {
        String coms=com[i].getcompanyname();
        String empd=emp[j].getempName();
        Company cos=emp[j].getcompany();
        if(com[i].getcompanyname().equals(empd)) {
            System.out.println(comp+" has "+empd+" as employees");
    }
        }
    }}
    
//employee array
public Employee[] saves() {
    save();
    Company[] com=save();
    Employee []emp=new Employee[5];
    emp[0]=new Employee(321,"rahul","manager","Male",907374383,City.KODUNGALLUR,com[0]);
    emp[1]=new Employee(654,"akhil","assistant manager","Male",703845983,City.KOZHIKODE,com[1]);
    emp[2]=new Employee(987,"mithun","supervisor","Male",598339834,City.KOCHI,com[2]);
    emp[3]=new Employee(721,"visakh","assistant supervisor","Male",339835300,City.TRIVANDRUM,com[3]);
    emp[4]=new Employee(548,"sharma","trainee","Male",545348945,City.THRISSUR,com[4]);
    return emp;
}
//prints all employees
public void showDatas() {
    saves();
    Employee[] emp=saves();
    for(int i=0;i<emp.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(emp[i].toString());
    }
    
}
```

}

To print all employees in a company.

There is a employee array which consists of all companydetails.

The companyname function is getcompanyname().The employeename function is getempName().

The companynames are "abc","cde","fgh","ijk","lmn".
The employeenames are "rahul","akhil","mithun"etc.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Company[] to Employee[]

```
at com.aitrich.yellowpages.YellowPages.empcompany(YellowPages.java:65)
at com.aitrich.yellowpages.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: Your save()-method returns an array of Company. In your method empcompany() you assign this to an array of Employee. That doesn't work.

Comment: you are somewhere trying to pass an array of Companies to what should reference to an array of Employees. Since they're not the same, this is not possible. Look at line 65 of your code

Comment: @RalfRenz@Stultuske can you pls write the code to print  employee in a company

Comment: And that is the reason for good method/variable names, so you dont confuse `save()` with `saves()`

Comment: _can you pls write the code to print employee in a company_ - isn't that your task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save()` returns an array of type `Company[]` but `Employee[]` is required. I think you wanted to call `saves()` instead: `Employee[] emp = saves();`.

In order to print all employees matching their company, you may want to do something like this:

```java
for(Employee e : employees) {
    for(Company c : companies){
        if(e.getCompany().getName() == c.getName()) {
            System.out.println(e);
            // rest of code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed that pls tell how to print employeename  from a companyname

Comment: Make a for-loop over your companies. Inside it make a loop over the employees. If the companyname in company is the same as in the employee than print the employee.

Comment: i tried,i dont know the right method to compare company name and employee name,companydetails will printed inside employee also,pls help to correct code,inside the empcompany function.

Comment: updated my anwser that it matches your request

Comment: @Dominik Lovetinsky sir i wanted to print employee in a given company

Comment: Updated again, now it should fit your requst

Comment: sir can u update according to my program.i dont know to take all employees and companies.can u do it with for loop.

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky   can you please me in  latest question that i have uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void empcompany() {
    save();
    Company[] com = save();
    saves();
    Employee[]emp=saves();
    String comp="fgh";
    boolean found=false;    
    int i=0;int j=0;
            
            while(j<emp.length) {
                String ce=com[i].getcompanyname();
                String ec=emp[j].getempName();
                Company cos=emp[j].getcompany();
                String coa=cos.getcompanyname();
                if(comp==coa) {
                        System.out.println(comp+" has "+ec+ " as employee");
                        break;
                        
                    }else {j++;}
                }
                }
```

Comment: Please open a new question and explain your problem you can than share the link to this question with me

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky sir here the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72527413/16618826